# JavaScript - how to read and display Network Path

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

Simple question yet I cant find a working solution.

I have asp net core app and I pass a network path to JavaScript by ajax request. Example is I pass a data of

```
string myNetworkPath = "\\\\192.10.11.12\\sharedfolder";
```

So in JS I can get the data and display it as "\\192.10.11.12\sharedfolder" as how I intended it to be read by the user.

But here's the problem, I have a button that will open a modal. In the modal, I also need to display the path as "\192.10.11.12\sharedfolder". What I did was I saved the value(myNetworkPath) to a JS variable, then read the variable's value in the modal.

Yeah I know you can already see the error here. In modal, it displays as "\192.10.11.12 haredfolder". Since I saved it in a variable the backslashes are interpreted as escape character. That's my problem guys. How can I save it to a variable and tell it not to interpret the backslashes as escape character? Or can you suggest other way to display the path to the modal. Thanks!

Comment: If JS can read and display the data, it can do so in a modal. You need to show your code so we can find the error.

Comment: sorry but the code i'm using is very simple really. I have a restore.js file, in top of the file I have var networkPath=""; After the ajax request I just save the return data to networkPath. Then in modal I use the variable like $("#networkPath_txt").val(networkPath);

Comment: Look, your question essentially says "In JS, I can display the string correctly, however in JS I can't display the string correctly". As you can see here, it works fine in theory https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/qo3f0v6g/ So whatever causes it to fail happens in your code. when you say `in JS I can get the data and display it as "\\192.10.11.12\sharedfolder"` what exactly do you mean by "display"?

Comment: In simple terms, What I'm really trying to say is how can I save a "\\192.10.11.12\sharedfolder" in a JS variable and get and display the value as also "\\192.10.11.12\sharedfolder"

Comment: My fiddle demonstrates how that is trivially possible; if it doesn't work for you, you need to post a [mre] that demonstrates the problem. Note that even if I remove the masking backslashes from my code, `\s` still doesn't turn into a space character, so there has to be some additional encoding / processing going on you haven't told us about yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo worked:

View:

```
  str0:&nbsp;
<input id="input1" style="width:300px" />
<br />

<button onclick="changedata()">change</button>
@section scripts{
    <script>
        function changedata() {
             $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetUrl","Test")',
            dataType: "json",
             }).done(function (data) {
                 var str = data;
                 alert(str);
                 $("#input1").attr("value", str);
               
    });

        }
    </script>
}
```

Controller：

```
 public IActionResult GetUrl() {
            string str= "\\\\192.10.11.12\\sharedfolder";
            return Json(str);
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: sorry sir, but you got the str value wrong. "\\\\192.10.11.12\\sharedfolder" is its value in c# variable, escape characters included. So when this is passed to ajax, it will be only "\\192.10.11.12\sharedfolder".

Comment: I have changed my answer,maybe you can pass a json type data to ajax liking in my answer.